# Adding Song with artist(!) to Android MediaStore

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I've been busy trying to insert a new Song into the Android 10 MediaStore for audio... Most of it works out of the box, so I am able to play the song, see its title and so on. However, when I query the MediaStore for all audios on my phone, the song shows up, but the column `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST` suddenly is `"<unknown>"` instead of the String I inserted before. I use the following code for inserting into the database:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, song.filename)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, song.title)
        contentValues.put(ARTIST, song.interpret)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, song.length)
        contentValues.put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            Calendar.getInstance().time.toString()
        )

...

val contentUri: Uri = Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
uri = contentResolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues)
```

I now suspect that either the artist I insert has to be "known" in some other MediaStore-Table holding known Artists or that Android scans the phone itself and maybe finds out that the new stored mp3-file has no artist in its ID3 metadata? Or do you think there is any other issue with my code?

---

**Follow up:**
I did some experiments and indeed, as @Theo suggested, the android scanning picks up all those values and even corrects them in case my own insertions differed from the files metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to add a track manually as the android scanning will take care of populating all the necessary fields. below a screenshot of (part) the table files
[image: android media table files]